# Undocumented C++ preprocessor directives (MSVC 2013u4)

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

In MS file apiset.h, there is the following preprocessor directive:

```
#define API_SET_BY_ORDINAL(X,O,PO)         X @##O NONAME
```

MS [help page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/teas0593.aspx) recognizes the stringify, charizing, and token-pasting preprocessor commands. '@' is not one of the [96 accepted characters](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases), and in MSVC the '@' before the '##' cannot be in an identifier.

Is the whole '@##' a preprocessor command? If so, what is its purpose? If not, how one should understand the above macro?

Comment: its to make a string "blah @1" have a look at .DEF files

Comment: How exactly did you get from "'@' is one of the 96 accepted characters" (which isn't true anyway) to "the '@' before the '##' cannot be a token"?  Letters are among the accepted characters, and they certainly appear in tokens.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I think he meant that `@` is _not_ one of the "96 characters of the basic source character set" (as per his link), and concluded it therefore can't be part of an identifier.  (The conclusion is incorrect)

Comment: Fixed the typo. Although '@' is not part of the basic set, that is not the reason it is not used as part of a token. My reasoning was incorrect. I edited the question to make it less offending. Nevertheless, using '@' in a token yields error C2018: unknown character '0x40'.

Comment: "If not, how one should understand the above macro?" By reading the documentation, or if there is no documentation, by looking for examples of where this macro gets used, what arguments are passed, and checking what it expands to. This header does not exist on my system, and a quick search does not reveal where it comes from (at least not any version containing the macro definition in your question). It would not surprise me if other readers will have the same problem.

Comment: Anyway, one thing to remember is that `##` can be used for any type of token, not just identifiers. Additionally, MSVC is tolerant of misuse of `##`: if the two tokens cannot be pasted together, no error is issued. So if some MSVC-specific context (perhaps inside some pragma?) can use a `@123` construct, then if macro argument `O` is `123`, `@##O` would produce a form of `@123` that could be used inside that pragma. This is all just random guessing, though. Getting a useful answer will require someone knowing how this macro gets used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Microsoft C/C++ compiler has never required that the result of the ## preprocessing operator be a valid preprocessing token. The intent of `@##O` is to paste a `@` character in front of a number given by `O` without any spaces in between. So `API_SET_BY_ORDINAL(GetSystemTime, 633, x)` will expand to `GetSystemTime @633 NONAME`. This macro isn't meant to be used in C/C++ code, it's meant to be used as part of an [EXPORT statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyx1zcd3.aspx) in a module definition (.DEF) file.

While this macro is new, other examples of ## that don't generate valid preprocessing tokens have been in Microsoft's headers for a very long time. For example I can find the following line in header from the July 2000 release of the Platform SDK header, the oldest version I have on hand:

```
#define _VARIANT_BOOL /##/
```

Note that `//` isn't a valid preprocessing token. Since there's is no `//` operator, it's two separate preprocessing tokens.

Comment: Not quite: another MSVC extension / peculiarity is that `/##/` gets turned into `//` and then gets treated as the start of a comment. It does not get treated as any tokens. (It would be two separate tokens as you say in standard C++, though.)

Comment: @hvd That doesn't actually contradict what I said. How the compiler interprets the result of pasting is a separate issue. In original poster's example, the compiler isn't meant to interpret the result at all. It's just supposed to emit the preprocessed file for the linker to interpret.

Comment: If it doesn't result in any tokens, and I don't believe it does, then it contradicts "it's two separate tokens." from your answer. :)

Comment: @hvd All I'm saying is that the result of pasting, `//`, is two separate preprocessing tokens thus isn't a valid preprocessing token. They compile accepts anyways, and I didn't say anything about how it interprets this particular result. Internally it may generate a result that represents it as one or two tokens. What it won't  and can't do treat the result as zero tokens, no tokens at all. Instead in a later step when it reinterprets the token sequence, it will remove these tokens (and any others following them) as part of comment removal.